# Is rest assured a good tool for automating more than 3000 Rest Api test cases?

Tags: api, automation, rest-assured

As I have to automate more than 3000 scenarios of rest apis. i am thinking to use Rest Assured.

Please share your experience is it good for such number of test cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Rest-Assured can cover your requirements but I strongly recommend you to write your own custom design framework depending requirements. You can use following libraries to write your own framework.

- Maven
- Rest-Assured
- Cucumber
- Object Mapper

You can also check my sample project at https://github.com/jawadk/automation-framework-project